# Adding NASA WELD Imagery to ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, imagery, nasa

How I would add WELD satellite imagery from NASA into ArcMap?

I'd like to take the entire CONUS scan and place it into ArcMap.

I tested a smaller scan of the Northeast, however I got a plethora of separate images.

Comment: How or where did you download them from ? Since you mention you test a smaller scan of the Northeast ?

Answer (score 1):

The plethora of images are various bands of data that WELD picks up and compresses it.Weld satellite images is version of contemporaneous Landsat 7 Enhanced Thematic Mapper Plus (ETM+) and Landsat 5 Thematic Mapper (TM) data. source http://landsat.usgs.gov/WELD.php

So you can go through ESRI's tutorial on using Landstat data http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009t0000023p000000